# Syntax error in UPDATE statement while update the data into msaccess database using c#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

**I want to change password in MS access database but it will not work properly & it shows Syntax error in UPDATE statement,Please help me friends.The database contain Register table with Roll,Name,Email,Password fileds **

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class DBConnect
    {
        private static OleDbConnection NewCon;
        private static string conStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=H:\MY FILES\PL\LIBRARY.mdb";

        public static OleDbConnection getConnection()
        {
            NewCon = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
            return NewCon;

        }
        public DBConnect()
        {

        }

    }


    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OleDbConnection dbConnection;


            dbConnection = DBConnect.getConnection();
            if (dbConnection.State.ToString() == "Closed")
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
            }

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Register SET Password=@Npwd WHERE Roll=@Roll AND Password=@Cpwd);", dbConnection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roll", "12cs0144");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cpwd", "434");
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Npwd", "123");
            int temp = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (temp != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("True");
            }
            dbConnection.Close();

            Console.ReadLine();
    }}}
```

Comment: Basically, use positional parameters instead of named parameters. Additionally, *always* specify the error in your question - "it shows syntax error" is not enough information. Also, you could have provided a much shorter example without the `DBConnect` class - you really only needed to call the `OleDbConnection` constructor.

Comment: Weird....Im not showing a syntax error